# Automatically exclude strings - Multilingual App Toolkit

Tags: c#, multilingual-app-toolkit

When using the Multilingual App Toolkit, our `resx` and `xlf` files contain lots of *junk* that we don't want translating (like a control's size and location).

[image: VisualStudio .NET WinForms example with resx file]

Is there anyway to automatically exclude all the extra information?

If not, is the only way to manually go through the XLIFF file using the Multilingual Editor and change `translatable` to False?

The problem is even worse when the resource file contains images...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A few days after asking here, I tried asking the same question at the [official support page](https://multilingualapptoolkit.uservoice.com/) for Multilingual App Toolkit, but I didn't get a reply there either.

So, as a workaround to the problem I've written a python script to set all of the properties other than `.Text` in the XLIFF files so that they are marked as `translate="No"`. The Multilingual Editor doesn't have an option to set "Translatable" as a bulk operation, and doing this manually would take forever.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from lxml import etree
import os


NEW_LINE = '\r\n'


def set_translatable(filepath):
    """
    Each string in the XLF file is set to translatable False unless
    it is the `.Text` attribute that we actually want translated.

    """
    doc = etree.parse(filepath)

    for d in doc.iter():
        if 'trans-unit' in d.tag:
            translate = False
            for k, v in d.items():
                if k == 'id':
                    if v.endswith('.Text'):
                        translate = True
            translate = 'yes' if translate else 'no'
            d.set('translate', translate)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as out_file:
        doc.write(out_file)


def main():
    cwd = os.getcwd()

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(cwd):
        for file in files:
            if filepath.endswith('.xlf'):
                set_translatable(filepath)          


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In Visual Studio, I also had to manually open every form and set the `Localizable` property to `True` so that the `.Text` values are saved in the corresponding `.resx` where the Multilingual App Toolkit can process them.

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't the toolkit XML Based?  Microsoft is ending XML support for their translation service and my unresearched understanding is that this will end up breaking the multilingual app toolkit...  if you know any more please share.

Comment: I assume (hope) that the MAT team are aware of this and will release an update that allows the MS translation service to still be used. There was an update when the translation service moved to Azure.

Comment: I corresponded with the author a couple of days ago on Twitter. I was trying to use a Custom Translation. Since the MAT only talks to the 2.0 version of the API, it cannot use Custom Translations. He mentioned he would see about speeding up the time-table to implement v3.0 API calls, but was not specific.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, however the above script didn't work for me. I am using MAT 4.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to ignore on a per-file basis, so this was helpful for me: https://multilingualapptoolkit.uservoice.com/forums/231158-general/suggestions/13627704-add-ignore-exclude-filter-for-resx-files

I basically added

```
<SuppressAutomaticLocalization>true</SuppressAutomaticLocalization>
```

in the EmbeddedResource tag in the .csproj file, resulting in:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Authorization\Components_Actions.resx">
    <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Components_Actions.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    <SuppressAutomaticLocalization>true</SuppressAutomaticLocalization>
  </EmbeddedResource>
...
```

More Info:
If the .resx File is not listed in your .csproj file, make sure to set the AccessModifier in the .resx file editor. If no selection is made, the file does not appear in the .csproj